# Command server of a qmgr is stopping automatically

Tags: ibm-mq

Command server of the QMGR is automatically going to stopped state with the below errors in logs. So client is not able to QMGR. could you plz check and help me to find permanent solution for this. Thanks in adavance

```
AMQ5053W: IBM MQ process 879 (amqrmppa) cannot be found and is assumed to be
terminated.

EXPLANATION:
A queue manager process has terminated, the queue manager will continue to run
but the functionality of the queue manager may be limited until the problem is
resolved. Possible reasons for the termination are: 1) A user has inadvertently
terminated the process. 2) The system is low on resources.  Some operating
systems terminate processes to free resources. 3) The process encountered an
error.
ACTION:
Check for earlier messages in the queue manager and system error logs that may
indicate the problem. When the problem is rectified the queue manager will need
to be restarted to restore the lost functionality.
----- amqxfdcx.c : 842 --------------------------------------------------------
12/14/21 12:03:14 - Process(413.3) User(root) Program(runmqlsr)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr("QMGR NAME")
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:14.010Z)
                    ArithInsert1(413)
                    CommentInsert1("QMGR NAME")

AMQ6184W: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred on queue manager "QMGR NAME".

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the IBM MQ error recording routine has been
called. The failing process is process 413.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: https://www.ibm.com/support/home/, or IBM Support Assistant (ISA):
https://www.ibm.com/support/home/product/C100515X13178X21/other_software/ibm_support_assistant,
to see whether a solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a
match, contact your IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the
problem has been resolved.
----- amqxfdcx.c : 888 --------------------------------------------------------
12/14/21 12:03:14 - Process(413.2) User(root) Program(runmqlsr)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr("QMGR NAME")
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:14.011Z)
                    ArithInsert1(545284135)

AMQ6125E: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred.

EXPLANATION:
An internal error has occurred with identifier 20806027.  This message is
issued in association with other messages.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: https://www.ibm.com/support/home/, or IBM Support Assistant (ISA):
https://www.ibm.com/support/home/product/C100515X13178X21/other_software/ibm_support_assistant,
to see whether a solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a
match, contact your IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the
problem has been resolved.
----- amqxfdcx.c : 842 --------------------------------------------------------
12/14/21 12:03:14 - Process(413.2) User(root) Program(runmqlsr)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr("QMGR NAME")
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:14.011Z)
                    ArithInsert1(413)

AMQ6183W: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the IBM MQ error recording routine has been
called. The failing process is process 413.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: https://www.ibm.com/support/home/, or IBM Support Assistant (ISA):
https://www.ibm.com/support/home/product/C100515X13178X21/other_software/ibm_support_assistant,
to see whether a solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a
match, contact your IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the
problem has been resolved.
12/14/21 12:03:14 - Process(409.1) User(root) Program(runmqchi)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr("QMGR NAME")
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:14.506Z)

AMQ9542W: Queue manager is ending.

EXPLANATION:
The program will end because the queue manager is quiescing.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqrimna.c : 1009 -------------------------------------------------------
12/14/21 12:03:14 - Process(412.1) User(root) Program(amqpcsea)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(AZMQES01)
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:14.807Z)
                    ArithInsert1(2009) ArithInsert2(2)
                    CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE                      )

AMQ8507E: Command server MQPUT1 request for an undelivered message failed with
reason code 2009.

EXPLANATION:
An attempt by the command server to put a message to the dead-letter queue,
using MQPUT1, failed with reason code 2009. The MQDLH reason code was 2.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqphrea.c : 86 ---------------------------------------------------------
12/14/21 12:03:14 - Process(412.1) User(root) Program(amqpcsea)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr("QMGR NAME")
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:14.807Z)
                    ArithInsert1(2009) ArithInsert2(2)
                    CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE                      )

AMQ8509E: Command server MQCLOSE reply-to queue failed with reason code 2009.

EXPLANATION:
An MQCLOSE request by the command server for the reply-to queue failed with
reason code 2009.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqphrea.c : 86 ---------------------------------------------------------
12/14/21 12:03:14 - Process(412.1) User(root) Program(amqpcsea)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr("QMGR NAME")
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:14.807Z)
                    ArithInsert1(2009) ArithInsert2(2)
                    CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE                      )

AMQ8506S: Command server MQGET failed with reason code 2009.

EXPLANATION:
An MQGET request by the command server, for the IBM MQ queue
SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE                      , failed with reason code 2009.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqphrea.c : 86 ---------------------------------------------------------
12/14/21 12:03:17 - Process(200.1) User(root) Program(amqzmgr0)
                    Host(303b0929d250) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr("QMGR NAME")
                    Time(2021-12-14T12:03:17.600Z)
                    ArithInsert1(412)
                    CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.CMDSERVER.1)

AMQ5025I: The command server has ended. ProcessId(412).

EXPLANATION:
The command server process has ended.
ACTION:
None.
```

Comment: "User(root)" - You should never ever run the queue manager under the root account.  Either login using mqm account or use sudo to switch to the mqm account then start and/or stop the queue manager.

Comment: Hi @Roger - Thanks for the Quick response. All our queue managers are running under root account only but we are facing issue only with this QMGR

Comment: The first log entry shows your queue manager is ending.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc and Roger, I have added the logs which are there on top of previous mentioned logs. Can u please have a look on it and suggest.

Comment: Are any FDC files produced?

Comment: @joshmc, Yes fdc's are generated.

Comment: What do they say.  Looks to me like the command server is not the problem,  your whole queue manager is crashing or getting killed.   I would suggest you patch to 9.2.0.4 and as Roger stated run as the mqm user not root.

Comment: FDC's are saying, probe description:An internal IBM MQ error has occurred.